# Sort values from Json response in ascending order and display in DOM

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON response for a field that is returned as space separated values

```
"contentTypes":"BALL APPLE BAT"
```

I want to map it to normal values and display it as a list in ascending order on the DOM

This is what I want

```
<ul>
  <li>Apple Fruit</li>
  <li>Ball Toy</li>
  <li>Bat Sports</li>
</ul>
```

This is what I got

```
 <ul>
      <li>Ball Toy</li>
      <li>Apple Fruit</li>
      <li>Bat Sports</li>
</ul>

if (value && value.length > 0) {
   return (
     <ul>
       {value.split(' ').map((value, index) => <li key={index}>{contentTypeEnumMap[value]}</li>)}
     </ul>
   )
}

export const contentTypeEnumMap = {
  APPLE: 'Apple Fruit',
  BALL: 'Ball Toy',
  BAT: 'Bat Sports'
}
```

Comment: Use `sort`? `value.split(' ').sort().map()`

Answer (score 1):

Well you just need to `sort` the `values` after the `split()` call, using **[`Array#sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**, it will give you the expected output:

```
if (value && value.length > 0) {
   return (
     <ul>
       {value.split(' ').sort().map((value, index) => <li key={index}>{contentTypeEnumMap[value]}</li>)}
     </ul>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` after `split`.

```js
const value = 'BALL APPLE BAT';


value.split(' ').sort().map(v => console.log(v));
```